# how to fetch a particular value using NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I need to fetch a particular managed entity where value is xxx.

my managed object is

```
Subscriptions : NSManagedObject{
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * category;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * frequency;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * alertType;
}
```

I need to fetch only the one entities where name is "xxx".
(There will be only one entities where name is xxx.)
I also need to fetch all entities where category is 1.

How can I do this using NSFetchRequest. I know how to use NSFetchedResultsController to fetch all entity values for an entity, but I want to fetch only one where name is xxx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a `NSManagedObjectContext *context`, then:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; //Note don't use autorelease if you're using ARC
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subscriptions" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSString *someName = @"xxx";
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name ==[c] %@", someName]; //[c] means case insensitive
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

The result array will contain all returned results and will be of type `Subscriptions`. If the predicate matches only one item there will be only one result, if matches none, the array would be initialized, but its `count` property would be 0. You may take a look at [NSPredicate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) and how you use it with `CoreData`.